# Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined vue js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a subscribe button I've written a small function but am getting the error above

```
methods: {
    subscribe(){
        firebase.messaging.requestPermission()
                          .then(() => {
                              console.log('Notification permission granted.');
                              return this.messaging.getToken();
                          })
    }
}
```

> Button

```
<button id="subscribe" @click="subscribe">Subscribe</button>
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't integrated the FCM JavaScript SDK correctly.

Comment: where am supposed to intergrate it?

Answer (score 1):

1.Install firebase to your project:

```
npm install --save firebase
```

2.Then add the messaging module in your project. E.g. `index.js` file.

```
import 'firebase/messaging'
```

3.Then use the messaging in your component:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

...

methods: {
    subscribe () {
        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
        messaging.requestPermission().then(
            ...
        );
    }
}
```

Just remember that the Firebase SDK is modular, Although you reference everything from the `firebase` package, If you don't include the referencing module *(messaging in this case)* in your final bundle, the firebase will complain about it missing.

Take a look at here for more information:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: am getting the error TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9___default.a.messaging.requestPermission is not a function"

Comment: Did you do the 2nd step?
And don't forget that **messaging is a function** not a property. So you should do it like this: `firebase.messaging().requestPermission()`

Comment: And did you try `firebase.messaging().requestPermission()` instead of `firebase.messaging.requestPermission()`?

Comment: firebase.messaging().requestPermission() is throwing an error  Deprecated symbol used, consult docs for better alternative

Comment: That's because `requestPermission()` method is deprecated. Take a look at here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging.html#requestpermission